# Cocos2D scheduleUpdate CCNode on SpriteKit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

In Cocos2D you can schedule a CCNode for updates by using the scheduleUpdate selector. SpriteKit does not include this (only for a SKScene).

What's the best way of accomplishing the same behaviour with SpriteKit? Is it safe to run a timer for each SKNode instance calling -update every second?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward the update calls to the receiving nodes. Either send update from the scene's update directly, or use delegation where you put all receivers in an NSMutableArray and during update send the update message to all objects in the array.

You should not use NSTimer or other timing mechanisms, because this will not guarantee when the timer fires. It could be before or after update, before or after didEvaluateActions and didSimulatePhysics, and when it fires may even change from frame to frame.